# Excel VBA 2010: I keep getting a declaration error: Compile Error: Duplicate declaration in current scope

Tags: vba, loops, compilation

I'm very new to VBA.  Loops always give me trouble.  I just can't seem to wrap my head around them (so, if anyone knows a good source to learn loops, I'm all ears).  Anyway, I've constructed the code below from a past project that I worked with a developer on.  I tried to reverse-engineer as much as possible from what he taught me - but truthfully, some of this I don't understand.  I simply want to get all records in sheet "Project Analysis" that match the project number in sheet "Breakdown" range C2 that and match these criteria if range F is greater than range E, and if the difference between the two is greater than 1.5, then take the associate name (D), assigned FTE (E) and Billed FTE (F) from "Project Analysis" and populate them to "Breakdown" on starting with range 32 (there's a pivot table in between).

The compile error occurs at "Dim StudyFound as integer" just prior to the start of the second loop.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmployeeBill()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim RecFound As Long
Dim LastRec As Long
Dim CollVar() As String             'Collect Labor/Bill data from Project Analysis
Dim StaffStudyInfo() As String      'Collect unique project number data
Dim StudyRec() As String            'Collect Unique Project name per Project Number
Dim StudyFound As Integer             'Collect number of valid records
Dim UniqueInfoFound As Long         'Collect number of valid records

'Collect Project ID, Associate, Assigned FTE, and Billed FTE records from Project Analysis tab
ReDim CollVar(LastRec, 4) 'Array to collect 4  data elements
LastRec = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row - 1
Sheets("Project Analysis").Select
RecFound = 0
For i = 1 To LastRec
    If ActiveCell.Offset(i, 3).Value = Sheets("Breakdown").Range("C2").Value Then
        RecFound = RecFound + 1
        CollVar(RecFound, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 3).Value 'Collect Project ID
        CollVar(RecFound, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 4).Value 'Collect Associate
        CollVar(RecFound, 3) = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 5).Value 'Collect Assigned FTE
        CollVar(RecFound, 4) = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 6).Value 'Collect Billed FTE
    End If
Next i

'Collect Associates who billed 1.5 times their FTE Assigned value
ReDim StaffStudyInfo(4, RecFound)
**Dim StudyFound As Integer**
UniqueInfoFound = 0
For i = 1 To RecFound
    StudyFound = 0
    For j = 1 To UniqueInfoFound
        If StaffStudyInfo(1, j) = CollVar(i, 1) Then
            If CollVar(i, 6).Value > CollVar(i, 5) Then
                If CollVar(i, 6) - CollVar(i, 5) > 1.5 Then
                    StudyFound = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If StudyFound = 0 Then
        UniqueInfoFound = UniqueInfoFound + 1
        StaffStudyInfo(1, UniqueInfoFound) = CollVar(i, 4) 'Associate
        StaffStudyInfo(2, UniqueInfoFound) = CollVar(i, 5) 'Assigned FTE
        StaffStudyInfo(3, UniqueInfoFound) = CollVar(i, 6) 'Billed FTE
    End If
Next i

'Populate all that meet above criteria onto "Breakdown" sheet
Sheets("Breakdown").Select
    For i = 1 To UniqueInfoFound
        Range("C" & i + 4) = StaffStudyInfo(1, i)   'Populate Associate
        Range("D" & i + 4) = StaffStudyInfo(2, i)   'Populate Assigned FTE
        Range("E" & i + 4) = StaffStudyInfo(3, i)   'Populate Billed FTE
    Next i
Range("A1").Select
End sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've already defined `StudyFound` near the top:

```
...
Dim StudyRec() As String            'Collect Unique Project name per Project Number
Dim StudyFound As Integer             'Collect number of valid records
Dim UniqueInfoFound As Long         'Collect number of valid records
...
```

Remove one of the definitions and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: Okay, I tried commenting the first declaration out.  I don't get an error, but nothing happens.  Would you be able to tell m where I'm going wrong in the code?  Like I said, I tried to reverse-engineer the code from a project I worked with an applications developer.  Would really like to know what I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I would change the `Range`s in your last loop to look like `Range("C" + (i + 4))`. `&` is designed to concatenate strings to strings, and I'm not sure of the operator precedence.

Comment: Okay, I did that (and changed it to row 31 since there is a pivot table above.  I didn't get any error, but nothing happened, either.  Like I said, I'm horrible at looks.  I'm wondering if did something with the arrays that is off.